# Updating the affectiva license

Tags: affdex-sdk

I participated in the Affectiva Hackathon, when their license was the 30 day free trial. I was excited to hear they have changed to allow those not trying to sell a free license. However, when I tried to convert to the updated free license when I try to launch the android app on my phone: "Unfortunately, Good Vibes has stopped." Good vibes is the app name.

I have followed the steps outlined on [Affectiva's web page](http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_2/android/)

However, I kept everything at 3.0.1 rather than 3.2.0, as I developed the app and it worked fine using the 3.0.1, and I'm just trying to get it back up and running with the updated license.

I believe the issue is that I need a new actual license file. In the original app I had a *mylicensefile.license* stored in my app/src/main/assets/Affdex directory. This stored the expiration date information and it was incorporated in the code like this:

```
camDetector = new CameraDetector(context,CameraDetector.CameraType.CAMERA_FRONT, cameraPreview);
String licensePath="mylicensefile.license";
camDetector.setLicensePath(licensePath);
```

So, my question is where do I get another license file? I don't see that anywhere in the instructions.

Comment: posting my comments as a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android SDK can be used without a license since [v3.1.1](http://developer.affectiva.com/whats_new/#windowslinuxandroid-sdk-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B311). 
I would suggest upgrading to the latest version. This states that the [license API's](http://developer.affectiva.com/pages/platforms/v3_2/android/javadoc/com/affectiva/android/affdex/sdk/detector/Detector.html#setLicensePath(java.lang.String)) have been deprecated. You can check on the [developer-portal](http://developer.affectiva.com/#pricing) to figure out if you qualify for a free license.